# Events -> Find Participants results in Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: civievent

I've running CiviCRM 4.7.31 on Wordpress 4.9.6.
When selecting Events -> Find Participants, I get the following warnings and a blank screen:

> Strict Standards: Static function CRM_Core_Task::permissionedTaskTitles() should not be abstract in .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Task.php on line 132
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Task.php:132) in .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php on line 926

Furthermore, when I go into the Events Dashboard, I get the following each time:

> Standards: Static function CRM_Core_Task::permissionedTaskTitles() should not be abstract in .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Task.php on line 132

Is this a bug or an issue with my setup possibly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [recorded](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21391) and fixed in later version of CiviCRM. You can either apply [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11693/files) manually to 4.7.31 or upgrade CiviCRM to 5.2.1.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you for this information. I applied the patch manually and it fixes the issue.